# jQuery отправка всей формы с помощью AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть одна форма, которая состоит из нескольких блоков, содержащих большое число текстовых инпутов и один инпут для загрузки файла. Форма работает при обычной отправке, но необходимо переделать её так, чтобы отправка происходила с помощью AJAX средствами jQuery. Можно сделать всё, перечисляя в методе `$.ajax` все поля, таким образом:

```
data: {
    input1: $('input[name="1"]').val(),
    input2: $('input[name="2"]').val(),
    ...
    input15: $('input[name="15"]').val()
}
```

Но может существует способ отправить всю форму целиком, не перечисляя поля?

Comment: Метод [serialize()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp) Вам в помощь.

Comment: $.post("url", $("form").serialize());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете получить все поля формы методом сериализации

```
var str = $("form").serialize();
data: {data:str};
```

а потом в параметрах пост запроса отправить все на сервер.